# How to use the default laravel authentication change using a different database name?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Laravel by default asks for a db called "laravel" and a users table called "users", but I named them in a different way and I want to make it works.
Below the error it gives me:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel.users' doesn't exist

EDIT: I kept the default config/database.php, changing nothing inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your database name in config/database.php (check connections array) to not user laravel database. Please check `.env` file too, for laravel database name references.

To not use `users` table you need to update your User class's `$table` property. (User class comes with default laravel installation).

`RegisterController/@validator` method need to be updated to for a different table.

Comment: Everything fine with my env file.
DB_DATABASE=mydbname

What do I have to change in my User class's? Please be more specific

Comment: did you run php artisan config:clear after you changed .env variable(s)

Comment: Yes I did. But the problem remains

Comment: could you edit your question and add database.php - also what about the users.table ?

Comment: Actually the error changed, sorry I didn't notice it: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'pyramid.users' doesn't exist.  Of course pyramid is my db name.

Comment: Did you update the table property of your Users class ? then it should work

Comment: What should I do exactly because maybe I haven't done it properly. I just added protected $table = 'nameofmytable'; inside User.php but it didn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212115/discussion-between-ersoy-and-apwnn).

Comment: What should I do exactly because maybe I haven't done it properly. I just added protected $table = 'nameofmytable'; inside User.php but it didn't work